# Getting indices of all the elements that contain given substring

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get the indices of all the elements which match a certain condition in `my_list`.

```
my_list = ['This is chapter 1', 'chapter 2 is here', 'Baseball Sport', 'Football Sport', 'chapter 13']
```

I want to get all the indices of the elements in `my_list` which contain the string `'chapter'`.
I've tried list comprehensions but I'm still new so ain't getting successful.

```
search = 'Chapter'

for k in range(len(my_list)):
    search_list = [i for i, search in enumerate(my_list)
                   if search.lower() in my_list[k]]
```

I'm probably doing some mistake here which can't yet identify. How can I get my desired result of indices?

```
search_list = [0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are redefining `search` within the list-comprehension and the new definition of it is being used. What you want is this:

```
my_list = ['This is chapter 1', 'chapter 2 is here', 'Baseball Sport', 'Football Sport', 'chapter 13']
search = 'chapter'
results = [i for i, item in enumerate(my_list) if search in item]
```

---

**Sidenotes:**

1. If you have the power to define `search` yourself, there is no point
   defining it as `"Chapter"` and call `.lower()` on it every time.
   Define it as `"chapter"` instead from the get go.
2. A list comprehension *replaces* an explicit for loop. Having both is in this case a mistake. You only need to loop once over the list.
3. `enumerate` is used in order to avoid indexing (`my_list[k]`). You are correct to use `enumerate` here; so use it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. As for the search I used it as an example here. I'm scrapping data from a webpage so I build the list in lower case and also use search in lower case to match results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
my_list = ['This is chapter 1', 'chapter 2 is here', 'Baseball Sport', 'Football Sport', 'chapter 13']

search = "chapter"

search_list = [index for index, val in enumerate(my_list) if search in val]
```

This gives the output as

```
[0, 1, 4]
```

which is your desired output IMHO. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
my_list = ['This is chapter 1', 'chapter 2 is here', 'Baseball Sport', 'Football Sport', 'chapter 13']

search = 'Chapter'
search_list = []
for i, k in enumerate(my_list):
  if search.lower() in k:
    search_list.append(i)
print(search_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```py
my_list = ['This is chapter 1', 'chapter 2 is here', 'Baseball Sport', 'Football Sport', 'chapter 13'] 

search = 'Chapter'

search_list = [i for i, str_to_search in enumerate(my_list) if search.lower() in str_to_search]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is best way to solve your problem :):

```
search_list = [i for i, str_to_search in enumerate(my_list) if 'chapter' in 
str_to_search]
```